# Why I can't open mysql 5.6.10 from terminal on Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: installation, command-line, mysql

I've always used Ubuntu to host my servers and I wanted to try the new MySQL version. So I downloaded MySQL 5.6.10 (`.deb`) from their official site and installed it like this:

[Tutorial for MySQL install](http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-install-mysql-5.6-on-ubuntu-12.10-including-memcached-plugin)

And everything worked nicely, except from when I was going to log in. I got this error:

```
root@person-ubuntu:/opt/mysql/server-5.6# mysql -u root -p
The program 'mysql' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
```

But if I run:

```
root@person-ubuntu:~# /etc/init.d/mysql.server status
```

I get the following output:

```
 * MySQL running (14429)
```

So can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly what step of that guide is wrong (or is missing), but you didn't installed the package to open the *mysql console* from a terminal.

To work with MySQL from a terminal, you have to install [the Client package](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/mysql-client-core-5.5/). As stated in your output, you can install it entering this command:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-client-core-5.5
```

---

A great guide, well written, step by step and with very useful information is [the Ubuntu community LAMP guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ApacheMySQLPHP). If you will install one component or all the packages, that guide will be really useful.

Comment: so what im doing atm is just an upgrade?

Edit:
so i just installed it and when i type "mysql", i get the same output -_- 

I feel so terrible at this :D

Comment: Have you tried with `sudo apt-get install mysql-client`?

Comment: @Lucio the most generic package is `mysql-client` since if the MySQL version in the repositories change, you will get people angry at you.

Answer (score 0):

Ulrich is correct. MySQL 5.6 is the Enterprise Edition and you shouldn't install the 5.5 client tools. If your basedir is **/usr/local/mysql**, this should work for you:

```
echo 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin' | sudo tee /etc/profile.d/mysql.server.sh
```

Log out, and log back in. You should be able to run "mysql" from the command line.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem with:

```
cd /usr/bin
rm -rf mysql*
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql\*
sudo dpkg -l | grep -i mysql
apt-get autoremove 
apt-get autoclean 
sudo apt-get install mysql-client mysql-server
```

I had this problem because I once deleted `/usr/bin/mysql` before.

Comment: Deleting `/usr/bin/mysql*` makes no sense and would not work without root-privileges.

Comment: Thank you for posting. I also deleted ```/usr/bin/mysql``` and couldn't find a solution to get mysql reinstalled correctly.

Answer (score -1):

Please do not install mysql-client-core-5.5 from the ubuntu repos into your 5.6 installation because it will most likely break it. The DEBs contain server and client. I suppose it is just a PATH problem.

Look at your PATH variable and locate your mysql binaries. If the bin directory of your MySQL installation is not in your PATH create a short shell script in /etc/profile.d which appends the MySQL binary directory to the Path and exports it. Afterwards log out and in again.